# PHP / Laravel - Saving an array to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a hard time understanding the basic attribute casting in Laravel.

I want to store some coordinates in my database:

```
$coordinates = [
     'x' => 100,
     'y' => 60,
     'h' => 250,
     'w' => 250,
];
```

To save the coordinates, I do this:

```
$field = StreamField::find(4);
$field->coordinates = $coordinates;
$field->save();
```

I have declared belows `casts` on my `Field` model:

```
 protected $casts = [
     'coordinates' => 'array'
 ];
```

When I then want to fetch the data, I do this:

```
$field = StreamField::find(4);
return $field->coordinates['x'];
```

In my migration, the `coordinates` column is created like this:

```
$table->json('coordinates')->nullable();
```

Now is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm doing this too

Comment: You can `json_encode( $coordinates);` while saving into db.

Comment: _"Now is this the correct way of doing it?"_ - Does it work?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It works, yes. However I am just a bit unsure if it should be encoded into `json` before adding it to the database, that's all.

Comment: If it's working even if it's array, then what's the problem?

Comment: @oliverbj As per the Docs there is no need to encode at our end, should be handled by Laravel only. What is not working for you in that above code?

Comment: If it works when you pass in an array, Laravel must already be doing something with the value, like encoding it as json, serialize it or something so there's no need for you to do anything extra. The question is, will you ever need to search for any of those values `x`, `y`, `h`, `w` separately? If yes, then you need to find out how Laravel actually saves the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct way of doing it. You can also save as XML as a string (whatever you prefer).

Altrought i would use getters and setters when saving coordinates in order to vertify input (if you need it). Because if any error occurs, the program would not write json but error (as a string).

Comment: In my opinion, the verification/validation should already have been handled in an earlier stage, before you try updating the model.